# how to solve Android error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am going to put other fragment inside a fragment on android.
in here, I want to solve the problem as follows.

**"java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."**

here are my code.

public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {

```
private View view_activity;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    view_activity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);
    onShowFragment("tab1");     
    return view_activity;
}

public void onShowFragment(String select_fragment) {
    Fragment fr = null;

    switch (select_fragment) {
    case "tab1":
        fr = new FragmentTab1();
        break;
    case "tab2":
        fr = new FragmentTab2();
        break;
    }
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_acticity_place, fr);
    ft.commit();
}
```

}

error occur on **view_activity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);**

please help me.

Comment: Try *view_activity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, null);* instead of *view_activity = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but result is the same. please help me again.

Comment: Post your fragment_activity xml. You propably have **fragment** in there

Comment: sorry Rami. it appear same error yet.

Comment: Is this line intentional:
`ft.replace(R.id.fragment_**acticity**_place, fr);`

or is it a typo ?

Comment: **fragment_activity.xml** what is in it ???